# Prove that $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $3|k-2$ implies $3|k^2-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm looking to answer this question Prove $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $3|k-2$ implies $3|k^2-1$. I'm not sure what to do. I'm trying to study but now I am getting stuck on these questions that don't give a lot of information.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2k-1=2(k-2)+4-1=2(k-2)+3

Comment: This is quite trivial. since $k=3x+2$, we have $(3x+2)^2-1=9x^2+12x+3$, which is always divisible by $3$.

Comment: If $3\mid k-2$, then also $3\mid k+1$, because $k+1=(k-2)+3$.

Answer (score 3):

**A start:** If $3$ divides $k-2$, then $k-2=3q$ for some integer  $q$, and therefore $k=3q+2$.

Now compute $k^2-1$, that is, $(3q+2)^2-1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$3|(k-2)\implies3|(k-2+3)\implies3|(k+1)\implies3|(k+1)(k-1)\implies3|(k^2-1)$$

Comment: Wow, I got more up-votes than the Jon Skeet of math stack exchange.

Comment: Damn, now we're equal.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a counterexample to the assertion, i.e. if there exist an integer $k$ and integers $q, q', r \neq 0$ such that
$$k-2 = 3q,\ k^{2} - 1 = 3q' + r,\ r = 1, 2,$$
then we have
$$(3q+2)^{2} - 1 = 3q' + r,$$
so that
$$9q^2 + 12q + 3(1-q') = r.$$
But $r = 1, 2$ is not divisible by $3$, qed.