# Proof for divisibility?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove either by contradiction or contraposition (using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic in either case) that:

$$
∀k ∈ \mathbb{Z}, [3|(k-2) → 3 |(k^2 - 1)]
$$

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: $$k^2-1=(k-2)(k+2)+3$$

Comment: A similar question, without the FTA request, was [asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909451/prove-that-forall-k-in-mathbbz-3k-2-implies-3k2-1) yesterday. The FTA part is rather unnatural, one needs much less.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $k^2 - 1 = (k^2-4) + 3 = (k-2)(k+2) + 3$